# Arbitrary rank array as function argument C#

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a function that must take as input an array with an arbitrary number of dimensions. Is there a way to write it knowing the type of the items (e.g. `double[,,]` for a 3D array of `double`) or should I just use an `Array` object?

Comment: Can you give us an example about how you want to use it?

Comment: An arbitrary number of dimensions necessitates using `Array`.

Comment: If you know that there will be less than N dimensions you can just have N overloads, one for each dimension in the valid range.  If you need to support very large numbers of dimensions you're...likely to run into problems beyond the type system not supporting it.

Comment: I want to implement FFT for n dimensions using a wrapper of fftw library. In general it uses a 1D representation of the input nD array in row-major order but I'd like to add some user friendly functions that take as input "real" n-dimensional array.

Comment: You could also create your own custom collection that has N dimensions, to which you could then solve this problem for that custom type.  If you are actually dealing with collections with lots of large arbitrary numbers of dimensions, that's probably worth doing, both so you can pass around typed collections easily, and also so you can write operations to act on it effectively.